# Where can i find log of portainer.io on docker?

Tags: docker, portainer

I just want to set up a fail2ban rule to prevent portainer connections, but I can't find a log file of UI connections, and can't even get into the container...
Version of portainer container : 2.6.3.

Comment: did you try `docker container logs portainer`? this should give you all the logs of portainer container

Comment: So yes I do have it, however I can't get the logs to be in a file to be able to exploit them, and its logs don't give me an error when someone enters the wrong credentials...

What I need for fail2ban is really the feedback from the nginx server, but I don't know how portainer works on that...

Comment: not quite sure how fail2ban works but if you want portainer logs in a file try `docker container logs portainer > portainer.log`